# How to GetOsVersion on Windows 10 using perl

Tags: perl, winapi, windows-10

I've been using Win32::GetOSVersion() perl function to get the destination's OS version. However, this API call does have support only upto Windows Server 2012.

http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-0.52/Win32.pm

```
OS                      ID    MAJOR   MINOR
----------              ---   -----   -----
Win32s                   0      -       -
Windows 95               1      4       0
Windows 98               1      4      10
Windows Me               1      4      90

Windows NT 3.51          2      3      51
Windows NT 4             2      4       0

Windows 2000             2      5       0
Windows XP               2      5       1
Windows Server 2003      2      5       2
Windows Server 2003 R2   2      5       2
Windows Home Server      2      5       2

Windows Vista            2      6       0
Windows Server 2008      2      6       0
Windows 7                2      6       1
Windows Server 2008 R2   2      6       1
Windows 8                2      6       2
Windows Server 2012      2      6       2
```

Is there any other way/approach where I can get the OS version on Windows 10 too?

Comment: Do some websearch. This question has been asked a bazillion times.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few other ways to get the raw data, which you could then parse to fit your application, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $ver = `ver`;

print "output of ver command: $ver\n";

my $reg = `reg query "HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion" /v "ProductName"`;

# alternatively query for 'CurrentVersion' rather than 'ProductName' above 
print "output of registry query: $reg\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

[Win32](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32) module uses `GetVersionExA` (see [Win32.xs](https://metacpan.org/source/JDB/Win32-0.52/Win32.xs)) and as per msdn:

> In Windows 8.1 and Windows 10, the GetVersion and GetVersionEx
>   functions have been deprecated. In Windows 10, the VerifyVersionInfo
>   function has also been deprecated. While you can still call the
>   deprecated functions, if your application does not specifically target
>   Windows 8.1 or Windows 10, you will get Windows 8 version (6.2.0.0).

Source: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx)

Also see: [IsWindows10OrGreater function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/desktop/dn905474(v=vs.85).aspx)

If you get to fix it, kindly open a pull request :)

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all (*"Is there any other way ..."*).